# Is the codimension of a space curve germ in its normalisation finite?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, singularity

Suppose we have a reduced curve $(C,0)$ in $(\mathbb{C}^n,0)$ with an isolated singularity in the origin, and we take the normalisation of $\mathcal{O}_{C,0}$, which should be isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}\{t\}$. Is it true that $\dim_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathbb{C}\{t\}/\mathcal{O}_{C,0}) < \infty$? For plane curve singularities this is true, but I needed puiseux parametrisation to show this, which doesnt exist for curves with higher embedding dimension, and I cant really find this result anywhere... Is it even true or this only holds for plane curve singularities? Any help and refference is appreciated.

Comment: Could you write out a little more context about what your setup here is? For instance, do you mean a holomorphic curve, an algebraic curve but in the complex topology, what?

Comment: It is a holomorphic curve and I only look at its germ in 0, and I use the classical topology. A bit more context is that if you have two germ of plane curves $f$ and $g$, and if you assume that they they dont have common component and $g$ is irreducible, then you can compute the local intersection multiplicity by taking a parametrisation of $g$, i.e. taking a map $t\mapsto (x(t),y(t))$ and then the multiplicity is the order of f(x(t),y(t)). What I want is to do this with $g$ a curve and $f$ a hypersurface, and the only missing step in the proof is this codemension being finite.